# ruby `pry`: can I edit classes defined on the REPL?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

Context: exploratory experimenting written directly in the REPL.

In `pry`, if I type `edit fn_name` I can open the definition of `fn_name` in an editor and change it. Say:

```rb
def fn_name
  puts 'fn_name'
end
```

I can also edit class methods if I type `cd ClassName` and `edit method_name`, say:

```rb
def method_name
  puts 'method_name'
end
```

But if I type `edit ClassName`, it fails with

```
Error: Cannot find a file for ClassName!
```

Is there a way to open the whole definition for a class? Say, something like:

```rb
class ClassName
  def method_name
    puts 'method_name'
  end

  def self.class_method_name
    puts 'class_method_name'
  end

  private

  def private_method_name
    puts 'private_method_name'
  end
end
```

Update: I'm not asking for `pry` to give me code listing for arbitrary classes from the standard library or otherwise. I'm specifically interested in editing classes that I have typed on the REPL.

Update 2: I see many comments being written in a defensive way, as if I'm criticizing the tool or claiming it should be this or that way. To be clear: I'm brand new to it and I had no idea how it works internally. I have no criticism of a tool I don't quite understand yet. I'm just trying to find my way around it.

All I want is to know whether something is possible or not, because I couldn't figure that out from the documentation. Some comments were very helpful and gave me some understanding of how the tool works.

So far my understanding is that what I'm looking for is not quite possible, but there are workarounds that could be good enough for me.

Also, to be clear: "That's not possible" is a totally fine answer. Even better if it comes with "but here's the next best workaround".

Comment: what do you need to view in the whole class? reading the documentation (https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/README.md) it seems the edit is very method based, but there is some 'ls' style things to let you inspect the class or object you're looking at that might help?

Comment: Why would you need `pry` for this at all? Just type in everything you have in the final code block.

Comment: You're asking a lot of `pry` here. Why not just edit in a separate file you load in?

Comment: I'm not asking anything of `pry`, I'm just wondering if it is possible to edit a class definition because that would be very helpful in development cycle.

"That's not possible" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: You can redefine the whole class if you want. Nothing stops you. The problem is that Pry expects classes/modules to be in files named according to a convention, e.g. the defintion of `MyClassName` should be in a file named `my_class_name.rb`. If you don't follow the convention, what is Pry supposed to open?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs it appears `pry` relies on introspection not naming convention. For instance things like `Method#source_location`.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I didn't know about that convention. Thanks for the information. As for class definitions entered on the REPL, does that get saved anywhere other than the history? What I found out is that instead of writing the class definition I just type `edit` and do it in the editor, I can later traverse history, and `edit` it. That hack sort of works, even though it's cumbersome.

Comment: @engineersmnky that bit about introspection was very helpful. Things are coming together in my head now. I can only see classes if I list constants, so it makes sense then why I can't edit their definition, only methods. So I guess either I write classes in some external file or I have to resort to the history edit trick I mentioned above. Not what I hoped for, but I can get by with it.